# Expression: "with value" vs. "evaluate to value"

Tags: c, language-lawyer, terminology, constant-expression

In the context of (constant) expressions: what is the difference between "with value" and "evaluate to value"?

Here are some quotes from C11 (emphases added):

> The constant expression shall be an integer constant expression. It shall **evaluate to** a
> valid fundamental alignment,

> The expression math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT shall **evaluate to** a
> nonzero value.

> There may be at most one default label in a switch statement.
> (Any enclosed switch statement may have a default label or case constant
> expressions **with values** that duplicate case constant expressions in the enclosing
> switch statement.)

> The defined macros expand to integer constant expressions **with values** ...

> The values given in the following list shall be replaced by implementation-defined
> constant expressions **with values** ...

> ... the expression is a valid integer constant expression **with value** one

Are "with value" and "evaluate to value" synonyms?

Comment: Maybe it's just as simple as: `1` has value 1, whereas `1 + 1` is an integer constant expression evaluated to 2.

Comment: IMO "with value" means the value after evaluation. For instance the standard has this note: ".... `static int i = 2 || 1 / 0;`  the expression is a valid integer constant expression with value one." I read that as "` 2 || 1 / 0` evaluate to the value one"

Comment: @Lundin, all the examples presented pertain to constant expressions (not necessarily *constants*).  It appears to me that the spec simply uses two distinct forms for conveying the same idea.  I'm inclined to think that the distinction is editorial / English-language based, not technical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are "with value" and "evaluate to value" synonyms?

**TL;DR: yes.**

---

The language spec does not formally define the term "evaluate", so we must rely on conventional English definitions, such as this one from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evaluate):

> to determine or fix the value of

In more mathematical context, such as applies to C expressions, I understand "<Y> evaluates to <X>" to mean that <X> is the value determined when <Y>  is evaluated.

The spec does define "value", but that definition does not shed much light on the question at hand.

I checked all the appearances of "with value <X>" / "with values that" and "evaluate to" in the C11 language spec (since that's the version referenced in the question). The former appears 10 times:

- [6.4.4.1/3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p3)
- [Footnote 118](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#note118)
- [6.7.2.2/3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p3)
- [6.8.4.2/3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.2p3)
- [7.6/6](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.6p6)
- [7.11.2/2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.11.2.1p2)
- [7.22.1.3/4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.3p4)
- [7.29.4.1.1/4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.29.4.1.1p4)
- [E/5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#Ep5)
- [H.2.1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#H.2.1p1)

There are also one or two closely-related forms, such as "with (positive) values that" in [E/6](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#Ep6).

The "evaluate to" form appears 9 times:

- [6.6/4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p4)
- [6.6/7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p7)
- [6.7.5/3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.5p3)
- [6.7.6.2/6](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p6)
- [6.10.1/1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p1)
- [Footnote 168](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#note168)
- [F.10/4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#F.10p4)
- [J.2/1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2p1) (2 appearances)

Many of those, in both categories, are about the values of constant expressions, but only a couple are related specifically to the values of *constants*.  The rest are about the values of expressions that are not necessarily constant expressions.

As far as I can determine, the two forms are used interchangeably with respect to C language concepts.  The only distinction I see is around English grammar and usage. The "with value <X>" form is used when a requirement on the value of an expression is presented in the context of a broader statement about the expression. The "evaluate to <X>" form is used when a requirement on the value of an expression is presented as a standalone statement.  The question presents several good examples of each.

This is an editorial choice.  It has no technical significance.

Comment: Thanks! Re: "broader statement and standalone statement": interesting observation. Extra: 1) As I understand, the following terms (widely used in C11) are (full) synonyms: "same", "match" / "matching", "identical". 2) Is it OK that standards use synonyms?

Comment: @pmor, (1) I am not prepared at this time, in this context, to do the same kind of analysis of that set of terms, but I am inclined to think that yes, those terms are used more or less interchangeably in the C language spec. (2) I don't see why not.